# cpu suddenly overheating - can it be software/firmware related?

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cooling, temperature

My HP Omen laptop freezes completely from time to time.

I've done a lot of research and investigation before posting this question.

I finally found something specific that might well explains the random freezes :

I've installed SpeedFan to monitor the CPU temperatures.

After 3-4 hours, I was hearing the fans, and saw the CPU temperature rising to 78 degrees, and staying in the 70's range, without going back to normal temperature, even though CPU and memory is running only at around 10% capacity.

So my question is :

Does sudden CPU overheat can only be caused by defect hardware ?

If not, might a system restore fix this ? (I'm talking about a restore from a system image back when I had no random freezes)

All HP diagnostics report no failure (disk, memory and processor's extensive tests).

Comment: I have never heard of cpu overheating due to hardware. You could check if the cool pasta on your cpu is still ok. If not you could try to apply some cool pasta. Friend of mine had this aswell and it was the cool pasta that solved it.

Comment: @SkyRamon I assume you meant "Paste" like Silicon?

Comment: @CheesusCrust Akward... Yes thats exactly what I mean. sorry my native language is not english.

Comment: @SkyRamon - Do you really meant "hardware" in "I have never heard of cpu overheating due to hardware." ?     Because "paste" is not a software :)    If it helps to keep a system cool, it doesn't explain the sudden overheat.  Can a system restore be beneficial ?

Comment: @trogne Oh like that. I read the title. Never heard of overheating due to software (except overclocking) yes system restore could help if the issue is really software related but I think its better to check the cool paste first and then check some other hardware to see if there is nothing wrong. maybe after that check software issues.

Comment: In my whole carer life only once I replaced damaged CPU! and that because the customer didn't use paste while the temp sensor OFF from the motherboard, Cleaning the heat sink always solve the problem, or replacing the FAN if you hear weird noise, While changing the thermal paste works if the laptop very old.

Comment: But my computer is only 6 months old. Already no more paste ?

Comment: In your case first I will check the Power management from BIOS, Try to change between Passive\Active FAN, and check the power management inside windows, second I will check the FAN if it works probably. Give me the Model number of your laptop!

Comment: Model number : 17-w018ca

Comment: I would first use compressed air to blow out any possible dust. If there is a constant 10%+ usage, there may be a background task that is continually running. 78C is not an overheating level temperature, and shouldn't be causing a complete freeze. I would maybe look at your disk usage and make sure that's not at 100% utilization when the freezing occurs.

Comment: @SkyRamon *"You could check if the **cool pasta** on your CPU is still ok."* I have some hot tortiglioni, what about you?

Answer (score 0):

CPU was not overheating at all. It was functionning correctly. The program (SpeedFan) I used to check the fan speed (SpeedFan and temperature is just plain wrong.